# How to change the position of a widget in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this quiz and I want to lower the position of the buttons so the user's finger can reach it easiar...

Like in this pic

[image: A picture of the app]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, can you include a sample code of what did you tried ?

Comment: You can try justifying it using `crossAxisAlignment` and `mainAxisAlignment`

Comment: I really didn't try anything to be honest

Answer (score 0):

I guess you used a Column widget in the body of your page.
so you can use the Spacer() widget.

You can find an example here : https://dartpad.dev/?id=e75b493dae1287757c5e1d77a0dc73f1

Comment: well sadly it didn't work because I used rows, and not columns.